# Create a Hangout On Air with a predefined user

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I'm looking for a way to connect 2 people through Hangout On Air where all the generated videos will go to a single Youtube user account. I'm almost sure that the AirPair service use this strategy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnN8v4osr18

I have did a research about it and haven't found a way to do that, neither the Hangout API provides the ability to create a Hangout.

What I think AirPair does is create a Hangout through a Bot user and send invitations to the couple of users. It's that or maybe there is a paid service the can bring that ability.

Do you have any idea about how it can be possible?

Comment: Have you found out anything? I started exploring the google hangout APIs and I couldn't find out how to create such an experience. I would need that too

Comment: No. What I have ended up doing is creating a Hangout app which post to my server the Youtube id of the generated video.